How to exclude logged sqls by regexExpresstion in p6spy
I want to exclude sqls: select count(*) from trade, insert into task,
how to config?
In spy.properties,belows doesn't work

dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS #this works, so spy.properties works.
filter=true
excludeconnectfilters=.SELECT\s+COUNT\s\(\s*\\s\)\sAS\s+total\s+FROM\s+trade\s+.,insert into xxx.*


Fixed, using sqlexpresion like this:
exclude sql like select or otherKeyWords:
filter=true
sqlexpression=^(?!.*select)(?!.*otherKeyWords).*$

